# Checking whether the line is parallel to the plane

Tags: regions, geometry

I have tried to write a code to check whether a line is parallel to the plane in Mathematica.
Using that a plane has the normal vector of $\vec{n}=(a,b,c)$ and a line has a direction vector $\vec{L}=(l,m,n),$ the condition is $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{L} = a \,l + b \, m + c \, n = 0$.
I have tried writing the following code:

```
{a, b, c, d} = {1, 2, 3, 4};
plane = ImplicitRegion[a x + b y + c z + d == 0, {x, y, z}];
{x0 , y0 ,z0} = {2, 1, 4}; 
{l , m , n} = {3, 1, 9};
line = ImplicitRegion[(x-x0)/l==(y-y0)/m==(z-z0)/n , {x,y,z}];
If[(al + bm +cn == 0),Return("parallel"),Return("not parallel")];
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.
What are the mistakes?

Comment: `al` is a single symbol; if you want to multiply `a` and `l` you use `a*l` or `a l`. Also, don't use `Return` unless you know what it's for; then, use it with square brackets `Return[...]` instead of round brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can give vector-values to variables and use scalar products:

```
planenormal = {1, 2, 3};
linedirection = {3, 1, 9};
planenormal.linedirection == 0
```

> False

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`RegionDisjoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDisjoint):

```
RegionDisjoint[plane, line]
```

> False

Answer (score 0):

```
{a, b, c, d} = {1, 2, 3, 4};

plane = ImplicitRegion[a x + b y + c z + d == 0, {x, y, z}];

{x0, y0, z0} = {2, 1, 4};

{l, m, n} = {3, 1, 9};

line = ImplicitRegion[(x - x0)/l == (y - y0)/m == (z - z0)/n, {x, y, 
z}];

If[(a*l + b*m + c*n == 0), Return["parallel"], 
Return["not parallel"]];
```

[image]